# Swift - como descobrir o tamanho do JSON?

Tags: swift, mobile

Estou recebendo um Json de um link. Como descubro seu tamanho e com isso como atribuo a chave "imagem" a um vetor de String -  `var img = [String]()`?

## exemplo JSON:

```
[{"imagem":"textoX","link":"link da webX"},
 {"imagem":"textoY","link":"link da webY"},
 {"imagem":"textoZ","link":"link da webZ"}]
```

## Pegando JSON e consultando:

```
func search(query: String) {
    guard
        let _ = query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()),
        url = NSURL(string:  "http://meusite.com.br/app/teste.php?a=1000")
        else { return }
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data where error == nil
            else { return }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            var error: NSError?
            let json = JSON(data: data, options: .AllowFragments, error: &error)
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
    //IMPRIMINDO JSON. . .       
            print("===json start")
            print(json)
            print("===json end")

    //CONSULTANDO JSON. . .

            print(json[0]["imagem"])  // CHAVE IMAGEM DA POSIÇÃO 0
            print(json[1]["imagem"])  // CHAVE IMAGEM DA POSIÇÃO 1
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Estou usando a `SwiftJSON.swift` e na `plist` estou com o `App Transport Security Settings`

Desta forma ele da print na resposta que desejo atribuir a uma [String]:

```
var int = 0
            for (key, subJson) : (String, JSON) in json {
                print("=======Passei aqui!!!=======")
                print(json[int]["imagem"])
                int = int+1

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer a iteração do JSON:

```
  let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
  for objeto in json {
    // preenche os arrays com os dados do JSON
    imagens.append(String(objeto["imagem"]))
    links.append(String(objeto["link"]))
  }
```

Depois é só usar os arrays:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código de exemplo está [neste playground do gist ;)](https://gist.github.com/iTSangarDEV/94aeafe88c3afecf2ace0fcefb06215f)

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer fazer uma iteração sobre o objeto `json` e ir adicionando ao vetor `img`, certo?

Considerando isso, você faz assim:

```
var img: [String] = []

for (index, subJson) : (String, JSON) in json {
    if let imagem: String = json[index]["imagem"] {
        img.append(imagem)
    }
}

// Resultado
print(img)
```

Comment: Exatamente isso porem, quando inclui seu código no escopo, ele me deu um erro na linha do for dizendo `'Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') is not convertible to '[String:String]'`

Comment: Ah sim, agora conferi na biblioteca qual o resultado deste método. Editei a resposta, veja se agora volta corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, ele identificou o for agora porem, esta dando o seguinte erro no if `Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an índex of type 'String'`

Comment: Assim não da erro porem, ele não entra no if `if let imagem: String = subJson["imagem"] as? String`

Comment: O que não estou conseguindo é saber qual objeto esta biblioteca é representada porque não consigo testar aqui, pela documentação também é difícil saber. Mas fiz outra tentativa, considerando que seu `json` é um *array*, como você informou.

Comment: Estou testando com um JSON que possui 3 conteúdos em seu escopo, ele esta identificando os 3, pois passa 3 vezes pelo for, porem o que não estou sabendo no momento e atribuir o valor do json no vetor [String]. Sou bem leigo no Swift, atualizei a pergunta. No final da pergunta com base na sua resposta. Ele da print nos valores desejados, so me falta saber como atribuir mesmo.